# How to push LSP Diagnostic using OmniSharp LanguageServer?

Tags: c#, omnisharp, language-server-protocol

I'm using OmniSharp's [C# LSP server](https://github.com/OmniSharp/csharp-language-server-protocol) to implement a simple parsing/language service for a VS Code plugin.  I've managed to get the basics up and running, but I've not been able to figure out how to push diagnostic messages to VS Code (like in [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide#explaining-the-language-server) typescript sample).

Does anyone have any sample code/hints that would be of use?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a code sample of your plugin? I'm looking for smth similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having spoken with @david-driscoll, it turns out I needed to stash a reference to ILanguageServerFacade in my constructor and use the PublishDiagnostics extension method on TextDocument.  Ie:

```
public class TextDocumentSyncHandler : ITextDocumentSyncHandler
{
   private readonly ILanguageServerFacade _facade;

   public TextDocumentSyncHandler(ILanguageServerFacade facade)
   {
      _facade = facade;
   }

   public Task<Unit> Handle(DidChangeTextDocumentParams request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   {
      // Parse your stuff here

      // Diagnostics are sent a document at a time, this example is for demonstration purposes only
      var diagnostics = ImmutableArray<Diagnostic>.Empty.ToBuilder();

      diagnostics.Add(new Diagnostic()
      {
         Code = "ErrorCode_001",
         Severity = DiagnosticSeverity.Error,
         Message = "Something bad happened",
         Range = new Range(0, 0, 0, 0),
         Source = "XXX",
         Tags = new Container<DiagnosticTag>(new DiagnosticTag[] { DiagnosticTag.Unnecessary })
      });

      _facade.TextDocument.PublishDiagnostics(new PublishDiagnosticsParams() 
      {
         Diagnostics = new Container<Diagnostic>(diagnostics.ToArray()),
         Uri = request.TextDocument.Uri,
         Version = request.TextDocument.Version
      });

      return Unit.Task;
   }
}
```

For real code, you would want a centralised array of Diagnostic objects, but this shows the basics of how to get it done.

Thank you David!